# Calling child method from parent method not working

Tags: python

I have a Parent and Child class as follows:

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__set_config():

  def __set_config(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

  def run(self):
    # do something

class Child:
  def __set_config(self):
    self.config = {"foo": "bar"}
```

The expectation is that, in the parent class's call to `__set_config()`, the child class's overridden method would be called. What in fact happens is that `NotImplementedError` is raised instead of the config object being set.

Is it not possible to

- enforce implementation in a child class of a method,
- and also call the same method in the parent class?

Comment: Those two underscores at the front of the variable made it a [Private variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=private#private-variables). If you changed the name to `_set_config`, it would work.

Comment: Also, `Child` does not inherit from `Parent`, so it wouldn't find the method anyway.